# PHPExcel don't give all data from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I use `PHPExcel` to export my table data to excel file

In my code i try to export from 2 tables in one excel sheet my code work but

The problem is i have all data - 1

what i mean if i have 5 rows should be in the excel file i receive only 4

This is my code:

```
<?php 
$project=$_POST['project'];


//populate the data

$row=4;
while($data=mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellvalue('A'.$row,$data->db_projectid)
    ->setCellvalue('B'.$row,$data->db_projectname) 
    ->setCellvalue('C'.$row,$data->loc)
    //incriment the row
$row++;    
}
//make table headers
$excel->getActiveSheet()
      ->setCellValue('A1','Project')
      ->setCellValue('A3','#')
      ->setCellValue('B3','Project Name')
      ->setCellValue('C3','Location');

if(mysqli_num_rows($activitieQuery)>0){
    $row=7;
while($data=mysqli_fetch_object($activitieQuery)){
$excel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellvalue('A'.$row,$data->db_id)
    ->setCellvalue('B'.$row,$data->db_activityname) 
    ->setCellvalue('C'.$row,$data->db_category)
    ->setCellvalue('D'.$row,$data->db_priority);

    //incriment the row
$row++;    
}
//make table headers
$excel->getActiveSheet()
      ->setCellValue('A6','Activities')
      ->setCellValue('A7','#')
      ->setCellValue('B7','Activity Name')
      ->setCellValue('C7','Category')
      ->setCellValue('D7','Priority');

}
//write the result to a file

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="project.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control:max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
$file=PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel,'Excel2007');
//output to php output instead of filename
$file->save("php://output");
exit;
 ?>
```

How can i receive all data i want without any problem.

when i print `mysqli_num_rows($activitieQuery);` i have number 5

and if i print for example `$data->db_id` i receive 5 ids not 4

But when i export to excel file i receive 4 ids not 5 how can i solve that?

For my first table i don't have any problem my problem is with the second table tbl_activities only any one have an idea how to solve that?

Comment: Please trim your code (remove all non-essential parts of your program). It serves two purposes: you can run a simpler test case on your end, and it is easier for us to read it. For example, the header generation part is irrelevant, and we don't need to know every single column of your output file. Also, you may want to test your loops outside of the Excel generation process, because I doubt that the problem is linked to Excel itself (e.g. just `echo $data->db_id` in the loops).

Comment: @RandomSeed please check the code above and in my loop i did what you say echo $data->db_id and i receive  5 ids not 4 but in the excel i have 4 and that is mention in my question thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with `$row = 7;` for your second query and then replace it with header

```
->setCellValue('A7', '#')
->setCellValue('B7', 'Activity Name')
->setCellValue('C7', 'Category')
->setCellValue('D7', 'Priority')
->setCellValue('E7', 'Supplier')
...
```

So replacing `$row = 7;` with `$row = 8;` should help

Comment: @Nikitia U thank you very much your answer help me and solve my problem